# error of importing scipy.stats in Eclipse and PyDev

Tags: python, eclipse, python-3.x, scipy, pydev

I am working on Python 3.3 on win 7.

I need to import scipy.stats but I got error

```
 Unused import: scipy.stats
 Unresolved import: scipy.stats
```

I have installed scipy (0.13.3) in site-packages folder of python 3.3.

I have added it in the PYTHONPATH in Eclipse + PyDev.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: All of the core SciPy Stack packages support Python 3, but some more specialist packages still only work on Python 2

Comment: can you `import scipy.stats` outside eclipse? like in plain python terminal?